# Hibernate search : single search term with space

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I am a newbie to hibernate search.

I am trying to implement a engine in which the results are exact matches.

**My persistence class changes**

```
@Field(index=Index.UN_TOKENIZED, store=Store.NO)

private String offerTitle;
```

**Implementation changes**

```
String[] offerFields = new String[] { "offerTitle"};
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_31,offerFields,new KeywordAnalyzer());
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = parser.parse(queryString);
org.hibernate.Query offerHibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Offer.class);
List<?> offerResults = offerHibQuery.list();
```

It works fine until the search term has space in it.  When search term contains space, it gets no results.

For example:  For the search term: "`Comcast offer name`" I get no results, and the query is broken into `offerTitle:Comcast offerTitle:offer offerTitle:name`

Is there any way to search for exact match with spaces?

I tried this:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder_1 = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Offer.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query offerCode_1 = queryBuilder_1.phrase().onField("offerTitle").sentence(queryString).createQuery();
org.hibernate.Query offerCodeHibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(offerCode_1);
List<?> offerCodeResults = offerCodeHibQuery.list();
```

It is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are not tokenizing the field, so you need to search with a single, unanalyzed term.  The simplest way to do that, I find, is to go straight to the Lucene APIs and just construct a `TermQuery`, like:

```
Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("offerTitle", queryString));
```

I think this should also work:

```
queryBuilder_1.keyword().onField("offerTitle").matching(queryString).createQuery();
```

Comment: I tried with TermQuery , which is not giving exact search,giving results consisting of keywords. for example my search term is "Comcast offer name" and results are entities with has title as "name" and "offer".

Comment: I also tried with query builder (second method u mentioned) and it is returning one object but all the entity values are null.

Answer (score 1):

```
queryBuilder_1.phrase().withSlop(0)
    .onField("offerTitle").sentence(queryString).createQuery()
```